# Bootstrap: tr class "warning" doesn't work in striped-table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a table defined `<table class="table table-striped">` with some rows like `<tr class="success">`, `<tr class="info">`, and `<tr class="warning">`.

The `success` and `info` table-rows show up fine: red and blue just as they should be. But the `warning` rows don't show yellow as expected. They're just regular, zebra-stripe white or gray.

Weird thing is, if I add `table-hover` to the table's classes, the `warning` rows will show yellow, but only when hovered. The `success` and `info` rows, however, always show their colors, hover or no.

Comment: I dont seem anyproblem http://jsfiddle.net/C9Phk/ , can you have your fiddle too ?

Comment: A matter of specificity probably. Either dive into the CSS files to see which rule overrides the `.table .warning` one, or simply make a new style rule with `.table .warning` and put put after the bootstrap styles.

Comment: Weird, it's working for me now too. I must've screwed up something else somewhere... thanks for the help, and sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, somehow I got this _exact_ same thing. Removing class `table-striped` shows the correct color, but with `table-striped` it just won't show.. Any idea how you fixed this? [edit] figured it out after a few minutes; the style for `.table-striped` got overruled by a second CSS, but the `.success` (etc) classes weren't that were supposed to overrule `.table-striped` weren't defined!

Answer (score 14):

Regarding this issue with v3.0.3 (which will be fixed in v3.1, whenever they release it), a quick/rough fix for this is to add `!important` overrides to some specific CSS for this issue:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr > .danger,
.table-striped > tbody > .danger > td,
.table-striped > tbody > .danger > th {
  background-color: #f2dede !important;
}
```

Obviously add this for `thead`, `tfoot` etc and `success`, `info` etc if you use those. I'm only using `danger`, and only in the `tbody`. I put these modifications in my bootstrap.css file, so that when I upgrade to v3.1 it will update anyway.

Comment: Notice for users of Bootstrap 2: We have the same problem here and _scrowler_'s solutions fix this at once! Yes, you can use `danger` (and other) classed rows in Bootstrap 2's stripped tables, with this small fix. Pity, that I can give you only +1, cause your solution is great!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this is a know bug in v3.0.3 and will be fixed in v3.1.0

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11728

For now I'm just going to remove class: table-striped to make the colours appear again.

Answer (score 0):

Related bug...
In Bootstrap 2.1.0, the "tr.warning" was left out, so that bootstrap.css was

```
.table tbody tr.success td {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.table tbody tr.error td {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
.table tbody tr.info td {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

But it should look something like:

```
.table tbody tr.success td {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.table tbody tr.error td {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
.table tbody tr.info td {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
.table tbody tr.warning td {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

Note the color choice for "tr.warning" is my choice, and not a Bootstrap default color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LESS and build your own bootstrap I suggest adding `!important` to the `bg-variant`-mixin:

```
// Fix for known bug bg-variant, fixes issues with striped tables
.bg-variant(@color) {
    background-color: @color !important;
    a&:hover,
    a&:focus {
        background-color: darken(@color, 10%) !important;
    }
}
```