# Bootstrap danger class not working for a table row

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following table in my Rails app:

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-striped'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class='danger'>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= order.status.name %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And the row with class 'danger' doesn't change the color. However, if I use the class 'success' it changes correctly.

I am using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

Comment: can you post a fiddle with this error? we don't have enought information to answer correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`twitter-bootstrap` gem is currently using `bootstrap v 2.3.2`.

And as per the [Bootstrap version 2.3.2 Documentation For Tables](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables) following are the available *row classes*:

```
Optional row classes

Use contextual classes to color table rows.

.success    Indicates a successful or positive action.
.error      Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
.warning    Indicates a warning that might need attention.
.info       Used as an alternative to the default styles.
```

Which is why `.success` worked but NOT `.danger`.

I suppose you are looking for `.error` class.

Answer (score 6):

it seems to be a know bug with tables.

> Looks like this is a know bug in v3.0.3 and will be fixed in v3.1.0

refer [this bug error page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11728) and this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864070/bootstrap-tr-class-warning-doesnt-work-in-striped-table)

Answer (score 2):

go through the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/#contextual-classes here they specified all row and cell classes, you should modify your

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-striped'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr class='table-danger'>//Modified line
    <td><%= order.id %></td>
    <td><%= order.status.name %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using an old version for the Bootstrap gem, by the way the default gem has not been updated to the version 3 of Bootstrap, try using this resource

https://github.com/jasontorres/bootstrap-on-rails

As @Kirti said the correct class for the Bootstrap 2 version must be `.error` instead of `.danger` watch the official documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables